# why does my for loop stop at the value of 200?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

My program should print out all three digit numbers which are divisible by its own figures for example 124 is divisible by 1, 2 and 4, it also should ignore all numbers with an 0 in it like 120 130 208 etc.
If I try to compile it in eclipse it just stops at 184 and I have no clue why. 
I'm a beginner at coding and sorry for bad English.

```
public class Teilbarkeitlol {
    public static void methode() {
        for (int zahl = 111; zahl <= 999; zahl++) {
            if (zahl % 10 == 0) {

            } else {
                int dig1 = zahl / 100;
                int dig2 = (zahl % 100) / 10;
                int dig3 = zahl % 10;
                if (zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(zahl);
                } else {}
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        methode();
    }
}
```

Comment: put a println in the second else block and you will see that the loop doesn't stop at 200.

Comment: Are you sure you don't get an error message? As soon as it hits 201, this will cause a division by zero.

Answer (score 1):

Your condition `if (zahl % 10 == 0)` only checks whether the last digit is `0`. You don't perform that check for the second digit (the first digit can never be `0` due to the range of the for loop).

change

```
if (zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0)
```

to

```
if (dig2 != 0 && dig3 != 0 && zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0) {
```

In this line when either dig1 or dig2 or dig3 becomes zero, your code is trying to do a division by zero operation. This happens at 201.

```
201%0
```

this gives an exception and your code stops at that point. (until that point your code skips those divisions by zero by skipping values divided by 10 :) ex: 120, 130 )

Solution would be check if dig1 or dig2 or dig3 is zero before performing that operation.

Also the blank if and else tags are not needed (not wrong either :))

```
else {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void methode() {
    for (int zahl = 111; zahl <= 999; zahl++) {
       if (zahl % 10 == 0 || (zahl % 100)/10 == 0 ) {
           continue;
       }

       else {
           int dig1 = zahl / 100;
           int dig2 = (zahl % 100) / 10;
           int dig3 = zahl % 10;
           if (zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0) {
               System.out.println(zahl);
           }

           else {
                continue;
           }

       }
   }}
```

Try This.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is throwing **java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero** because your "should ignore all numbers with an 0" part is incorrect. You can also do it by converting a number to String and checking of accourance.

```
    for (int zahl = 111; zahl <= 999; zahl++) {
        if (!Integer.toString(zahl).contains("0")) {
            int dig1 = zahl / 100;
            int dig2 = (zahl % 100) / 10;
            int dig3 = zahl % 10;
            if (zahl % dig1 == 0 && zahl % dig2 == 0 && zahl % dig3 == 0) {
                System.out.println(zahl);
            } else {

            }

        }
    }
```